# oracle timestamp without seconds

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have a timestamp(6) column in a table in my database. I would like to do a comparison on it but without considering the seconds part. I know that I can trunc(timestamp) to remove the time and leave the date part. Is there a way I can set the seconds to 0?

I want to do this:

```
CASE WHEN ARR NOT BETWEEN FROM AND TO THEN 1
     ELSE 0 END "mismatch"
```

..but get mismatches when the `ARR` has a seconds part greater than `FROM` and `TO`. I dont care about seconds and only want to consider minutes.

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What about `trunc(timestamp * 24 * 60)` ?

Comment: thanks for reply. If I do that  I get ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got TIMESTAMP

Comment: instead of truncating, I believe you can change your logic to work with seconds.. it should be better.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [`trunc()` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions201.htm) allows you so decide how much of the precision to discard via the optional `fmt` parameter; the default is to remove all time components, i.e. the equivalent of `trunc(x, 'DD')`. If you want to only lose the seconds you can use `MI`:

```
select systimestamp, trunc(systimestamp, 'MI') from dual;

SYSTIMESTAMP                        TRUNC(SYSTIMESTAMP,'MI')
----------------------------------- ------------------------
06-JAN-14 13.11.33.046920000 +00:00 2014-01-06 13:11:00
```

Note that the value returned from `trunc` is now a `DATE`, not a `TIMESTAMP`. If that is an issue - which is may well not be - you can cast it back:

```
select systimestamp, cast (trunc(systimestamp, 'MI') as timestamp) from dual;

SYSTIMESTAMP                        CAST(TRUNC(SYSTIMESTAMP,'MI')ASTIMESTAMP)
----------------------------------- -----------------------------------------
06-JAN-14 13.14.43.270506000 +00:00 2014-01-06 13:14:00.000
```

Comment: Thanks @AlexPoole When I run select systimestamp, trunc(systimestamp, 'MI') from dual; I get the same as if I ran select systimestamp, trunc(systimestamp, 'DD') from dual; I seem to lose all times

Comment: @RNJ - do you mean the time is displayed as `00:00:00`, or is your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` hiding the date part? You can `to_char()` it to show the time, but leave it as a date for the comparison.

Comment: Cool thanks Alex!  I never knew that trunc() had this optional parameter.